# Linux で全ディレクトリのパーミッション・所有者情報を一括で取得するには？

Tags: linux

仕事で表題の件を命じられました。

とりあえずやり方がわからなかったため、rootユーザで `/` へ移動し `ls -lR` と実行しました。

正直ファイルの権限についてはあまり重要ではないのですが、全ディレクトリ及びそのまた下層ディレクトリのパーミッション・所有者設定まで一括で取得するとなりますと上記のコマンドしか浮かばなかった次第です。

何か別にもっと良い方法がございましたらご教授頂きたく思います。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、ファイルは含まないでよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

こんなのとか

```
# find / -type d -print0 | xargs -0 ls -ld
```

Answer (score 1):

いっそ`find`の`-ls`を使って

```
find / -type d -ls
```

とか

Answer (score 1):

**find + stat**

```bash
$ find / -type d -exec stat -c '%n %A %U %G' {} +
```

**GNU findutils**

```bash
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.8.0

$ find / -type d -printf '%p %M %u %g\n'
```